# ORA-01113: file # needs media recovery ORA-01110

Tags: oracle

I have mistakenly added datafile to the tablespace... And was trying to drop it. I run the following:

```
alter database datafile 'datafile_name'  OFFLINE;
```

now when I run

```
alter database datafile 'datafile_name'  ONLINE;
```

it shows

```
ORA-01113: file 30 needs media recovery
ORA-01110: data file 30: 'datafile_name'
```

also status of the file is RECOVER... What can I do? I cant restart database....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
SQL> recover datafile 'C:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\10.2.0\ORADATA\ORCL\EXAMPLE02.DBF';

alter database datafile 'C:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\10.2.0\ORADATA\ORCL\EXAMPLE02.DBF' online;

alter  TABLESPACE EXAMPLE  drop datafile  'C:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\10.2.0\ORADATA\ORCL\EXAMPLE02.DBF'
```

But for production DB it needs a lot of time to recover... Can't I drop that file without recovering it?

One more question...
Another datafile was available during adding that file.. is there any chance that newly created datafile was used for storing data? I think oracle uses datafile until it will not exceed its maximum size and then switching to another available file... is not it so?

I am asking this because I want to be sure that newly created file doesn't contain any necessary data...

Comment: Please ask the "one more question" in the body of your question in stead of in your answer (or possibly as a new question if you think that would work better)!

Answer (score 3):

As soon as you add a datafile to an existing tablespace, a segment inside this tablespace that needs space may allocate an extent within the new datafile.

It will not wait until the other datafile(s) are full.

This is actually a feature (called extent striping) that was introduced to spread I/O across multiple devices, should datafiles reside on different drives. It is standard behavior since I don't know when - probably from the very start :-)

Comment: I thought like that and fortunately did not delete that datafile.... Thank you very much for useful information.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following commands if you can point your database to good backups and archive logs.  Here is a good Oracle Doc for your reference, which described a similar issue:  Fixing a Corrupted SYSAUX Tablespace (Doc ID 950128.1)

```
    SQL> alter database datafile 2 offline;
  rmand> restore datafile 2;
  rmand> recover datafile 2;
    SQL> alter database datafile 2 online;
```

Comment: why should  the datafile be restored? that makes no sense.